# start a VMWare workstation VM in a minimized window

Tags: vmware

Running VMWare Workstation on Windows 10

I use vmrun.exe to start a VM (.vmx file), this works but the VM is always displayed in maximized window on the host.

I need a VM to start in minimized window, only showing in Windows taskbar.

Note: this is not the same as NOGUI option, I want a gui but just minimized.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: If a Windows guest you can try starting on Unity Mode to see if that does what you need

Comment: What happens if you make a shortcut to vmrun.exe with the correct vmx command line and set it to run minimized?

Comment: Since you're using a Windows host, you could use `start "" /min PATH\TO\vmware.exe -x PATH\TO\VM.vmx`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, this does not work.